# Average amount of cars/day if fine=YES

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, mean

Sorry guys, I'm new here:
I want to see the average amount of cars that get a fine per day in my dataframe. So I want to make an average of the cars that get "Fine=Yes" per day.  How can I do this?

```
df
Car  Fine  Date
1     Yes  10/10/2017
2     Yes  10/10/2017
3     Yes  10/10/2017
4     No   10/10/2017
5     No   11/10/2017
6     Yes
7     No
8     Yes
```

So i can get 1 number: an averge amount of cars that get fined per day

Thanks

Comment: Just do a group by operation i.e. `df1 %>% group_by(Date) %>% summarise(Mean = mean(FIne == "Yes"))`

Comment: But i want to see 1 number: an average amount of cars that get fined per day.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [tidyverse](https://www.tidyverse.org/) package, you can do it the following way:

First, I read in the data like this:

```
df <- tibble(
  "Car" = 1:9,
  "Fine" = as.factor(c("Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No")),
  "Date" = as.factor(as.Date(c("10/10/2017", "10/10/2017", "10/10/2017", "10/10/2017", "11/10/2017", "11/10/2017", "11/10/2017", "11/10/2017", "11/10/2017"), "%d/%m/%Y"))
)
```

This pipeline does what you want:

```
summary <- df %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  summarise(ratio = sum(Fine == "Yes")/n())
```

The output is:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
        Date Ratio
      <fctr> <dbl>
1 2017-10-10  0.75
2 2017-10-11  0.40
```

You can transform your data.frame into a tibble by using the `as.tibble()` command. For the `group_by()` command, I transformed the 'Date' column into a factor.